# Get remaining seconds from input HH:mm in bash (OSX)

Tags: bash

I want write a simple bash script. Input is "HH:mm" string and the output is remaining seconds to that time, for example

```
$ getsec.sh 12:55 # now it's 12:30. so 25 minutes left.
1500
```

I thought using `date` command would probably the solution of this. But it seems like it doesn't exist the simple way that I can use.

---

(Added after checking some answers)

It looks like the `date` command depends on OS and version.
I use OSX, and the result of the suggested answer is as follows.

```
$ date -d '12:55' '+%s'
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Comment: ah yes I think OSX uses freeBSD `date` not GNU date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *BSD (and thus OSX) `date` command has a different option syntax than GNU `date`, which is ubiquitous on Linux and available on many other platforms (including OSX, with Homebrew, Fink, etc).

```
now=$(date -j +%s)
then=$(date -j -f '%H:%M' 12:55 +%s)
echo "$((then-now)) seconds left"
```

For a portable solution, maybe use a portable scripting language instead.

Comment: Off topic: `-d` means different in `GNU` & `BSD`. (`GNU` `-d` is `BSD` `-j`) Is it a better practice to use long options (`--date` in this case)? Because that long option would be called unknown option & command would likely fail, instead of interpreting the argument in wrong way.

Comment: @anishsane You need the date to be in the canonical format, or pass an `-f` option, for that to work.  Also, the meaning of `-j` is unrelated; without this option, *BSD `date` attempts to set the system clock.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
ts=$(date -d '12:55' '+%s')
now=$(date '+%s')

diff=$((ts-now))
```

Comment: Off topic: `-d` means different in `GNU` & `BSD`. Is it a better practice to use long options (`--date` in this case)? Because that long option would be called unknown option & command would likely fail, instead of interpreting the argument in wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

This script accepts the target time as a command line argument (accessed in the script as the parameter `$1`

```
#!/bin/bash

current_time=$(date +%s)
target_time=$(date +%s --date="$1")

# evaluate the difference using an arithmetic expression
echo "seconds remaining to target time: "$(( target_time - current_time ))
```

usage:

```
% ./get_sec.sh "22:00"
```

output:

```
seconds remaining to target time: 16151
```